# Load initial text from shared prefs in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to have an initial text (of my choice) at first and if the user changes it, it should save in Shared Preferences and load as initial text next time in a TextField.
Edited code a bit but it's still same, I think I'm going wrong somewhere with Shared Preferences.

```
String initialSignatureText = 'Sent from Mail';
TextEditingController _signatureController = TextEditingController();

String signatureText;

  void convertSignature(){
    String convertedSignature = _signatureController.text;
    setSignature(convertedSignature);
  }

  void setSignature(String convertedSignature) async{
    SharedPreferences signPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    signPrefs.setString('signatureTextKey', convertedSignature);
  }


  Future<String> getSignature() async {
    SharedPreferences signPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    signatureText = signPrefs.get('signatureTextKey');
    print(signatureText);
    return signatureText;
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _signatureController.text = signatureText;
TextField(
maxLines: 1,
style: TextStyle(
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
fontSize: 18
),
controller: _signatureController,
showCursor: true,
),

 FlatButton(
 child: Text('Ok'),
 onPressed: (){
   convertSignature();
   Navigator.pop(context); 
},
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I've not implemented to load initialSignatureText for first time, I'll do it later.

```
TextEditingController _signatureController = TextEditingController();
  String initialSignatureText = 'Sent from Mail.';
  var signatureText;

  void convertSignature(){
    String convertedSignature = _signatureController.text;
    setSignature(convertedSignature);
  }

  void setSignature(String convertedSignature) async{
    SharedPreferences signPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    signPrefs.setString('signatureTextKey', convertedSignature);
  }

  Future<String> getSignature() async {
    SharedPreferences signPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    signatureText = signPrefs.get('signatureTextKey');
    return signatureText;
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSignature();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _signatureController.text = await getSignature();
    });
  }
```

Comment: the "WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async..." is very helpful if you want to set an initial async value on a Textfield, in My Case: shared Preferences provided by riverpod. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any string to the text property of your controller

```
_signatureController.text = "any string";
```

The second way to do this would be to use [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html), It provides you with intialValue property.